# Delphi: Construction not calling overridden virtual constructor

Tags: delphi, constructor, virtual, delphi-5

i have an example descendant of `TBitmap`:

```
TMyBitmap = class(TBitmap)
public
    constructor Create; override;
end;

constructor TMyBitmap.Create;
begin
   inherited;
   Beep;
end;
```

At run-time i construct one of these `TMyBitmap` objects, load an image into it, and place it into a `TImage` on the form:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   g1: TGraphic;
begin
   g1 := TMyBitmap.Create;
   g1.LoadFromFile('C:\...\example.bmp');

   Image1.Picture.Graphic := g1;
end;
```

Inside of `TPicture.SetGraphic` you can see that it makes a copy of the graphic, by constructing a new one, and calling `.Assign` on the newly constructed clone:

```
procedure TPicture.SetGraphic(Value: TGraphic);
var
   NewGraphic: TGraphic;
begin
   ...
   NewGraphic := TGraphicClass(Value.ClassType).Create;
   NewGraphic.Assign(Value);
   ...
end;
```

The line where the new graphic class is constructed:

```
NewGraphic := TGraphicClass(Value.ClassType).Create;
```

correctly calls my constructor, and all is well.

---

i want to do something similar, i want to clone a `TGraphic`:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   g1: TGraphic;
   g2: TGraphic;
begin
   g1 := TMyBitmap.Create;
   g1.LoadFromFile('C:\...\example.bmp');

   //Image1.Picture.Graphic := g1;
   g2 := TGraphicClass(g1.ClassType).Create;
end;
```

Except this never calls my constructor, nor is it calling `TBitmap` constructor. It's only calling `TObject` constructor. After construction:

```
g2.ClassName: 'TMyBitmap'
g2.ClassType: TMyBitmap
```

The type is right, but it doesn't call my constructor, but identical code elsewhere does.

**Why?**

---

Even in this hypothethetical contrived example it's still a problem, because the constructor of `TBitmap` isn't being called; internal state variables are not being initialized to valid values:

```
constructor TBitmap.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FTransparentColor := clDefault;
  FImage := TBitmapImage.Create;
  FImage.Reference;
  if DDBsOnly then HandleType := bmDDB;
end;
```

---

The version in TPicture:

```
NewGraphic := TGraphicClass(Value.ClassType).Create;
```

decompiles to:

```
mov eax,[ebp-$08]
call TObject.ClassType
mov dl,$01
call dword ptr [eax+$0c]
mov [ebp-$0c],eax
```

My version:

```
g2 := TGraphicClass(g1.ClassType).Create;
```

decompiles to:

```
mov eax,ebx
call TObject.ClassType
mov dl,$01
call TObject.Create
mov ebx,eax
```

### Update One

Pushing the "cloning" to a separate function:

```
function CloneGraphic(Value: TGraphic): TGraphic;
var
    NewGraphic: TGraphic;
begin
   NewGraphic := TGraphicClass(Value.ClassType).Create;
   Result := NewGraphic;
end;
```

doesn't help.

### Update Two

Clearly, i'm clearly providing a clear screenshot clearly of my clearly code that clearly shows that my clearly code is clearly all there clearly is. Clearly:

[image]

### Update Three

Here's an unambigious version with `OutputDebugString`s:

```
{ TMyGraphic }

constructor TMyBitmap.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
    OutputDebugStringA('Inside TMyBitmap.Create');
end;

function CloneGraphic(Value: TGraphic): TGraphic;
var
    NewGraphic: TGraphic;
begin
    NewGraphic := TGraphicClass(Value.ClassType).Create;
    Result := NewGraphic;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    g1: TGraphic;
    g2: TGraphic;
begin
    OutputDebugString('Creating g1');
    g1 := TMyBitmap.Create;
    g1.LoadFromFile('C:\Archive\-=Images=-\ChessvDanCheckmateIn38.bmp');
    OutputDebugString(PChar('g1.ClassName: '+g1.ClassName));

    OutputDebugStringA('Assigning g1 to Image.Picture.Graphic');
    Image1.Picture.Graphic := g1;

    OutputDebugString('Creating g2');
    g2 := Graphics.TGraphicClass(g1.ClassType).Create;
    OutputDebugString(PChar('g2.ClassName: '+g2.ClassName));

    OutputDebugString(PChar('Cloning g1 into g2'));
    g2 := CloneGraphic(g1);
    OutputDebugString(PChar('g2.ClassName: '+g2.ClassName));
end;
```

And the raw results:

```
ODS: Creating g1 Process Project2.exe ($1138)
ODS: Inside TMyBitmap.Create Process Project2.exe ($1138)
ODS: g1.ClassName: TMyBitmap Process Project2.exe ($1138)
ODS: Assigning g1 to Image.Picture.Graphic Process Project2.exe ($1138)
ODS: Inside TMyBitmap.Create Process Project2.exe ($1138)
ODS: Creating g2 Process Project2.exe ($1138)
ODS: g2.ClassName: TMyBitmap Process Project2.exe ($1138)
ODS: Cloning g1 into g2 Process Project2.exe ($1138)
ODS: g2.ClassName: TMyBitmap Process Project2.exe ($1138)
ODS: g1.ClassName: TMyBitmap Process Project2.exe ($1138)
```

And the formatted results:

```
Creating g1
   Inside TMyBitmap.Create
g1.ClassName: TMyBitmap

Assigning g1 to Image.Picture.Graphic
   Inside TMyBitmap.Create

Creating g2
g2.ClassName: TMyBitmap

Cloning g1 into g2
g2.ClassName: TMyBitmap

g1.ClassName: TMyBitmap
```

### Update Four

i tried turning off all compilers options i could:

[image]

**Note:** Don't turn off `Extended syntax`. Without it you cannot assign the `Result` of a function (*Undeclared identifier Result*).

### Update Five

Following @David's suggestion, i tried compiling the code on some other machines (all Delphi 5):

- Ian Boyd (me): Fails (Windows 7 64-bit)
- Dale: Fails (Windows 7 64-bit)
- Dave: Fails (Windows 7 64-bit)
- Chris: Fails (Windows 7 64-bit)
- Jamie: Fails (Windows 7 64-bit)
- Jay: Fails (Windows XP 32-bit)
- Customer Build Server: Fails (Windows 7 32-bit)

[Here's the source.](http://www.jet2.net/~iboyd/CannotCloneTGraphic.zip)

Comment: Maybe you should tamper with compiler directives, some optimizations might affect virtual method table calls for your code and do not affect VCL library as it's precompiled.

Comment: @too, for example, which compiler directive affect virtual method table calls to occur correctly?

Comment: @Ian are you sure the g1.classtype is still TMyBitmap just before the last line of your Button1Click routine?  I bet the class is somewhere changing in the not shown lines.  As @David, I get two beeps also in  Delphi XE, I have no D5 at hand to test, but it seems unlikely a bug like this is present at that time to me (not even in D1). :)

Comment: @jachguate I tested with Delphi 2010 and Delphi 6. Clearly @Ian has got some extra code that we can't see.

Comment: @David Heffernan. i've updated the question with a screenshot of my code

Comment: @Ian Sorry, but I'm not going to type in your code from a screenshot!!

Comment: @jachguate i've updated the question to a version of the code that does ODS of class names. i'm sure `g1.ClassType` is still `TMyBitmap` just before the last line of my event handler.

Comment: This is a very long question, indeed!

Comment: @David: Naturally you were supposed to OCR the bitmap!

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand i just wanted to keep any readers up to date on things i'd tried, or evidence i'd collected. (i.e. not like it'd created the question and given up).

Comment: @Ian Great that it's finally been solved. I knew it had to be something that the rest of us could not see, but I don't think I'd ever have worked it out without access to D5 source. I never doubted that you had a problem, by the way, I just couldn't work out what it could be. I've now deleted my answer because it is no longer useful to anyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a scoping problem (the following is from D5 Graphics.pas):

```
TGraphic = class(TPersistent)
...
protected
  constructor Create; virtual;
...
end;

TGraphicClass = class of TGraphic;
```

You don't have any problems overriding `Create`, and you don't have any problems when `TGraphicClass(Value.ClassType).Create;` is called from within the Graphics.pas unit.

However, in another unit `TGraphicClass(Value.ClassType).Create;` does not have access to protected members of `TGraphic`. So therefore you end up calling `TObject.Create;` (which is non-virtual).

### Possible Solutions

- Edit and recompile Graphics.pas
- Ensure your clone method subclasses lower down the hierarchy. (e.g. TBitmap.Create is public)

### EDIT: Additional Solution

This is a variation on the technique to gain access to the protected members of a class.
No guarantees on the robustness of the solution, but it does seem to work. :)
You'll have to do your own extensive testing I'm afraid.

```
type
  TGraphicCracker = class(TGraphic)
  end;

  TGraphicCrackerClass = class of TGraphicCracker;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: TGraphic;
  b: TGraphic;
begin
  a := TMyBitmap.Create;
  b := TGraphicCrackerClass(a.ClassType).Create;
  b.Free;
  a.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Well holy hell. You sir win +100 internets. That is exactly the problem, and exactly the solution. **+1 Extraordinarily helpful** answer that answers the exact question. i used the well known "**Cracker**" solution. i presume that in later versions of Delphi, the constructor of `TGraphic` was promoted to `public`, which is why nobody was able to reproduce it?

Comment: @IanBoyd The `TGraphic` constructor was made `public` in Delphi 6.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth: I downloaded your source (the ZIP file), and ran `CannotCloneGraphics.exe` and got a "Not valid." error message. Then I opened the project (the DPR file) in Delphi 2009, compiled it, and ran it. Then I didn't get any error message, and the custom constructur ran four times, as it should.

It would thus seem like this is an issue with your Delphi 5 installations. Indeed, *all* your machines had Delphi 5 (time to upgrade?!). Either there is some issue with Delphi 5, or all your machines have been "tampered" with in the same way.

I am pretty sure I have an old Delphi 4 <del>Personal</del> somewhere. I might install it and see what happens there...

## Update

I just installed Delphi 4 Standard in a virtual Windows 95 system. I tried this code:

```
  TMyBitmap = class(TBitmap)
  public
    constructor Create; override;
  end;

  ...

  constructor TMyBitmap.Create;
  begin
    inherited;
    ShowMessage('Constructor constructing!');
  end;

  ...

  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    g, g2: TGraphic;
  begin
    g := TMyBitmap.Create;
    g2 := TGraphicClass(g.ClassType).Create;
    g.Free;
    g2.Free;
  end;
```

and *I only got one message box!* Therefore, this *is* a problem with Delphi 4 (and 5), after all. (Sorry, David!)

Comment: Finally, someone else with the issue. i agree that it's time to upgrade, but i'm not the person in charge of that polotical decision. This makes the answer "Issue with Delphi 5 (and more)". So i'll rate this answer **+1** - **very** helpful. i'll have to see if Craig's answer actually works around the bug.

Comment: You don't need to apologise to me. I never doubted what Ian was saying, I just couldn't reproduce it or imagine what it was that meant he saw different behaviour. In the comments you'll see that I called out the fact that nobody else had tried with D5 and that was indeed the issue.